# How to set GTK theme on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (like you could in 20.04)?

Tags: 22.04, themes, gtk, lts, gnome-tweaks

I have just switched from 20.04 to 22.04 LTS, and I am having issues with my previous GTK theme. I was using the gnome-tweaks app and the place where I set my GTK theme before (used to be called "applications") is now called "legacy applications," and as expected it only works on older apps. For example, the gnome-tweaks app and my file manager use my custom theme, but the extension-manager app does not, nor do most pop-up windows such as when downloading things from my browser (these just use the default yaru theme). I am very confused as to why this no longer works - is gnome-tweaks just too out of date? Is there any way to change the full GTK theme? Thank you in advance!

[Image shown for demonstration - top app "gnome-tweaks" uses my theme, bottom app "extension-manager" does not. Red arrow pointing to the place that used to be for gtk theme ("applications), but now says "legacy applications."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkPfK.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu switched to Gnome 4 and also to gtk4. Your theme is expected to have a `gtk-4.0` folder inside, which might help you with those apps, that are written for GTK-4.

So "legacy applications" are apps written against GTK3- if they are no "snap" apps. Snap ignores mostly any theme settings except those it provides itself.

Since GTK4 comes also with a "libadwaita" library it renders more external themes unusable. I've written some remarks on how to install a theme [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1424967/) and circumventing the [libadwaita](https://blogs.gnome.org/alatiera/2021/09/18/the-truth-they-are-not-telling-you-about-themes/) theme problem...

To sum it up:

- Your "legacy (GTK-3)" apps will accept your theme as long as they are
  debs and not snaps.
- Your GTK4 deb apps will accept your theme if it    supports GTK4

Comment: Thank you, your blog post is very enlightening! I had already done some work on switching my old theme from gtk3 to 4 at the time I posted this question, but I basically just copied over the `gtk.css` file from the `gtk-3` directory into the `gtk-4 `directory under `~/.themes/<theme_name>`. However, this seemed to make no difference - is there a step I am missing here? Is the issue that apps using the "libadwaita" library will not be able to run off this older CSS that I have copied over from gtk3?  I am new to theming in ubuntu so apologies if my questions are confusing.

Comment: It might provide some changes - so it should make an effect - but some CSS keys have been changed. (Currently I rewrite my theme for GTK4 from scratch). So buttons might be changed, but menus are not. Note that the directory's name must be `gtk-4.0`. Switch the theme forth and back, so the apps will recognize the change.   BTW: if answers in this forum help you, you should accept them. Later readers will know that they have been verified by the OP